# How to return from a list-generating, recursive function using `take`

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a function that recursively generates an infinite list, but never returns:

```
f n ns = f (n+1) (n:ns)
```

With lazyness in mind, do I need a return condition or can I do something to make it return using `take 10 $ foo 0 []`?

Comment: Your function is tail recursive. Tail recursion is equivalent to a while loop and a while loop without terminate condition will never return.

Comment: Your function is not even defined in purely mathematical sense. What do you think the first element of `foo 0 []` is?

Comment: Btw, there is no reason to think that your function returns a list. If you examine its type in GHCi, you'll get something like `f :: (Num a) => a -> [a] -> b`. The nature of that `b` cannot be anyhow restrained. To put simply, `f` always returns something returned by `f`, and that is something returned by `f`, and that's something returned by `f` and so on ad nauseam.

Comment: I think you wanted `f n = n : f  (n+1)` which indeed would create an infinite list you could `take` away from for example with `take 10 $ f 0` - btw: you can mostly forget everything about tail-recursive calls using Haskell - it's usually an non-issue with lazy thunks ... of course you get other trouble you might want to think about - but for stuff like this? ... Relax and just think about the *math* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function never returns at all. It always recurses. If you want it to ever return, you need to either add a stopping condition of some sort, or make it return a partial result.

Perhaps you actually meant to write something like

```
f n = n : f (n+1)
```

which returns `n` followed by a recursive call to generate the rest of the list. (?)